# Loging into an FTP with .NET

Tags: .net, ftp, webclient

On the [WebClient page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) i see the following

> By default, the .NET Framework
>   supports URIs that begin with http:,
>   https:, ftp:, and file: scheme
>   identifiers.

The FTP i am using requires a login. How do i login with WebClient to download a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the credentials on the WebClient object, e.g.

```
Dim ftpReq As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(filename)
ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
ftpReq.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("anonymous", "password")
```

See [here](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/windows/2006/12/12/building-ftp-services-using-net-20.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Credentials property of the WebClient to your FTP username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass in [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx).